# How to Replace <br\ /> tag

Tags: java, android

We are developing a app. In which we getting a data from a json array . In that i want to replace a  tag.But the emulator throws an error .Like Invalid Syntax .
my code:

```
top=top.replaceall("<br\/>"," ");
```

Please help. Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 8):

use

```
top=top.replaceall("<br\\/>"," ");
```

instead of

```
top=top.replaceall("<br\/>"," ");
```

**EDIT :** maybe String.relpaceall not work. so best way is use Regular Expressions's Matcher as :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<br\\/>");
String tempstr = "I love <br/>  <br/>  <br/> <br/>.";

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(tempstr );
String tmp = matcher.replaceAll("Android");
System.out.println(tmp);
```

**OUTPUT IS:**

### "I love Android. Android Android Android."

Comment: I tried there is no error this time . But it not replacing the tag. @ Imran Thanks

Comment: In any Strings you need to escape backslashes. The way this is done is by putting two backslashes instead of one.

Comment: @Deepu : plz post your String in which you want to replace

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
String res = Html.fromHtml(yourString).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
top=top.replaceall("<br\\/>"," ");
```

Comment: I tried there is no error this time . But it not replacing the tag.@ Quoi Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the emulator throws an error,because  top.replaceall(""," ")  is wrong,

the correct written is  top.replaceall(""," "),you must use Escape Sequence.

i try it in my application,that's right.